# Element of ultrafilter without minimum

Tags: real-analysis, filters

I want the shortest possible proof of the following statement:

Let $x$ be a nontrivial ultrafilter on $\mathbb{R}$.

For every $X\in x$ there exists a set $Y$ such that $X\supseteq Y\in x$ and $Y$ has no minimum.

Comment: @Frpzzd I thought about considering all cases: ultrafilter without limit point (at positive infinity and at negative infinity), ultrafilters with a limit point (two cases: an ultrafilter containing the left axis from this limit point and an ultrafilter containing the right axis from this limit point). But can this be solved in an easier way?

Comment: You won't be able to prove this. For instance, $\mathbb N$ could be an element of $x$.

Comment: @Andrés: Ha. Good timing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The claim is false. If $\Bbb N$ is in the ultrafilter, then every subset of $\Bbb N$ which is also in the ultrafilter will have a minimal element.

Comment: But does it hold for all *convergent* ultrafilters on $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: The claim is false even for convergent ultrafilters: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2304587/4876