# Element of convergent ultrafilter without minimum

Tags: real-analysis, filters

In continuation of [Element of ultrafilter without minimum](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2304439/4876):

Let $x$ be a nontrivial convergent ultrafilter on $\mathbb{R}$.

Prove or disprove:

**Statement** For every $X\in x$ there exists a set $Y$ such that $X\supseteq Y\in x$ and $Y$ has no minimum.

My attempt to solve:

Let $x$ converges to a number $\alpha$. Then we have either $\mathopen]\alpha;+\infty\mathclose[\in x$ or $\mathopen]-\infty;\alpha\mathclose[\in x$. In the first case it is quite easy to prove (take $Y=X\cap\mathopen]\alpha;+\infty\mathclose[$). But how to prove (or disprove) it in the case $\mathopen]-\infty;\alpha\mathclose[\in x$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not true in general.  For instance, let $(\alpha_n)$ be an increasing sequence which converges to $\alpha$ and let $x$ be an ultrafilter that contains the set $X=\{\alpha_n\}$ and converges to $\alpha$.  Note that $X$ is order-isomorphic to $\mathbb{N}$, and in particular any nonempty subset of it has a minimum.  So for any $Y\subseteq X$ in $x$, $Y$ must have a minimum.